# Replace characters in between string?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have the following string:

```
string input = "  2  1";
```

It is `2 spaces` followed by a `2` and then `2 more spaces` followed by a `1`.  I want to do a replace on it, but I only want to replace the spaces between the `2` and the `1` with 0's and I do not want to use RegEx if possible?

The end result should look like this:

```
string result = "  2001";
```

`20 340400    1` - `20-34-04-00-00001.0-0000.00`

`20 340400  500` - `20-34-04-00-00500.0-0000.00`

`20 340900    C` - `20-34-09-00-0000C.0-0000.00`

`20 3435OG    1    1` - `20-34-35-OG-00001.0-0001.00`

`20 3435OG    2   10` - `20-34-35-OG-00002.0-0010.00`

`20 3435OG    A` - `20-34-35-OG-0000A.0-0000.00`

`20 3436AA    1    4A` - `20-34-36-AA-00001.0-0004.A`

`20 3436AA    2   10B` - `20-34-36-AA-00002.0-0010.B`

`20 353100  268` - `20-35-31-00-00268.0-0000.00`

`20G3402AI    1    401` - `20G-34-02-AI-00001.0-0004.01`

`20G3403AI    7    1` - `20G-34-03-AI-00007.0-0001.00`

`20G3416MK        1701` - `20G-34-16-MK-00000.0-0017.01`

`21 3410OM       148` - `21-34-10-OM-00000.0-0147.00`

A few things I have noticed is that the first 4 parts are put together, most of the spaces and decimals are removed.  I have had success without regex in most cases, but it fails for some.

Comment: Can there be any other characters in the input string apart from a '2', a '1' and some spaces?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a regex?

Comment: You need to generalize what you're asking, because there's 112 ways, starting with: `string result = "  2001";`

Comment: @MarkByers - Yes, there can be other characters.

Comment: @WillVousden - I was curious if it would be possible without Regex, but I am not opposed to using it.

Comment: @Xaisoft can you describe *all* possible inputs? rather than '  2 1' explain "I have a input like _____, and I want to replace _____ with ____"

Comment: OK, I will post a bunch of examples, hold on.

Comment: I don't really see how your examples relate to the question.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to get from one pattern to the other.

Comment: The new data is what I start out with from the very beginning.  I was at a point where I needed to insert 2 0's between `  2  1`, so that is why I asked that.

Comment: @Xaisoft did you get an answer on question `how to insert 2 0's between ' 2 1'` without regex?

Comment: I've modified the question a bit. Please edit it back if I moved it in the wrong direction.

Comment: @dtb I think it should be another question. You invalidated all answers (most of which were correct) by this edit.

Comment: @dtb - I think that is more in line of what I am trying to ask.

Comment: I have no problem duplicating this question to another if you feel that is best

Comment: @Xaisoft so I think your problem is that you haven't thought about your question clearly enough.  Could you write the signature of the function you're hoping for?  Then could you give two or three example inputs and the output you're hoping for?  That will help you clarify what your actual problem is...As it is, your question is confusing (which is why people are down voting).

Comment: It is best I create another question.

Comment: One that looks like this: git://gist.github.com/4047866.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
static string ReplaceSpacesWithZerosExceptLeading(string s)
{
    return s.TrimStart(' ').Replace(' ', '0').PadLeft(s.Length);
}
```

This will remove the leading spaces, then replace the rest with zeros, then put the leading ones back on.

EDIT: Never mind, this answer already exists...

Comment: This worked well enough for this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "  2  1";
string result = string.Format("  {2}00{4}", input.Split(' ')); //Gives "  2001"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = input.TrimStart().Replace(' ', '0'); // "2001"
```

If leading spaces are important, then:

```
var result = input.TrimStart().Replace(' ', '0').PadLeft(input.Length, ' ');
```

Comment: He's got leading spaces in his 'result'...

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl I believe we both answered before he edited with that update...

Comment: @JWiley, I must have missed seeing it w/out the update....

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl no problem, updated

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - This does the trick for this particular one, now if I could only get it working for the other patterns.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - Actually, there are 2 spaces before 2001 and I need to preserve both, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: @Xaisoft Sorry, I don't see how your new input data related to your initial question. And both spaces are preserved in my solution.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - That is what I start of with, I was just at a part with `  2  1`, so that is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(Input.Trim()).Replace(" ", "0");`

Answer (score 0):

You really should use RegEx for this, but you could also try:

```
input.Replace(input.Trim(), input.Trim().Replace(" ", "0"));
```

Obviously it's not optimal, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
string txt = "  2  1";
string txt1 = txt.Substring(0, (txt.Length - txt.TrimStart().Length)) + txt.TrimStart().Replace(" ", "0");
Debug.WriteLine(txt1);
```

or if the number is within range

```
long num = long.Parse(txt.Replace(" ", "0"));
txt1 = num.ToString().PadLeft(txt.Length);
Debug.WriteLine(txt1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun you can use Linq:

```
string result = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                   new string(input.Take(3).ToArray()), //get first three values
                   "00", //insert 00
                   new string(input.Skip(5).ToArray())); //get last value
```

Comment: This does not remove the dashes, dots and it probably won't work for all inputs.

Comment: I wrote this before you changed the question. So you want to remove the dashes and dots and replace them with white spaces and then insert 00?